# In VB.net, how do create a forward of a message in Outlook and then update a category of the source message once I send the forward?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, vb.net

I want to make a VB.NET Outlook AddIn that will let the user automatically create a forward of a selected message (prepopulated with a specified email address/subject line), display it for review, and then, after the user successfully sends the forward, add a specific category to the *original* message, e.g., "Processed."  If the user instead closes the forward without sending it, then nothing should happen to the original.

I have the reply generation feature fine, and the category setting feature--what I'm at a complete loss for is how to, in effect, pause execution of the sub until the forward is either sent or canceled/closed out, and then have different follow-on actions for the original email depending on how the forward was disposed of.

My code below:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim itm As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim fwd As Outlook.MailItem
    Try
        itm = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    Catch ex As Exception
        Exit Sub
    End Try
    fwd = itm.Forward
    fwd.Recipients.Add("<email address here>")
    fwd.Subject = "Test Email"
    fwd.Display()
    'more code here that waits for forward "fwd" message to be disposed of and then branches 
    'to handle the original "itm" message differently depending on how the "fwd" was disposed
    'of...
    itm.categories = "Processed"
    itm.save()
End Sub
```

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't believe you can wait inside your `sub` for the email to be sent. You'll probably have to look at using the `MailItem.Send` event to identify the forwarded email you created and then run the relevant additional code.

Comment: Agreed with Richard. You may need to take a further look at the MailItem.Send or MailItem.Forward event.

Comment: Yeah, after I did some more research last night, I came to the same conclusion.  I figured out that the email header's In-Reply-To property contains the Message-ID of the "parent" message (the message the forward is of).  My thinking was that I could have a MailItem.Send routine that inspected the In-Reply-To property of the forward, extracted the Message-ID of the parent message, and then used that to find the parent message in the inbox and mark it appropriately.  However, accessing those properties is proving challenging.  Am still looking into it....  Any advice is welcome, of course.

Comment: @user2325786 Using the `Message-ID` would seem like a sensible approach to me. I've never tried it though.